# Check for driver

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm writing a Mac application which needs to check whether a given driver has been installed or not.

How can I go about checking this?

BR,
S.

Comment: It would be a USB-Serial driver: http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp?id=31

Comment: There does seem to be a kext installed: ProlificUsbSerial.kext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to grep output of `kextstat` for its name, knowing that `grep` returns nonzero exit code when nothing is found:

```
if (0 == system("/usr/sbin/kextstat | /usr/bin/grep -qF com.company.KextName"))
{
     // it is loaded
}
```

If you need to do that directly, check [`kextstat` source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/kext_tools/kext_tools-42/kextstat_main.c), you'll find it's using `kmod_get_info` API, however I can't find any documentation on it right now. I see no serious disadvantages in using `system()` call, so I'd stick with it.